# Big O Notation of a module nested in a built-in method in Python

Tags: python, performance, methods, coding-style, big-o

I'm wondering about a rationale for determining the big O values behind built-in methods in Python. Given the following operation:

```
i_arr = ['1','2','5','3','4','5','5']

s_arr = sorted(set(i_arr))
```

My rationale is that this is `sorted(set) = n^2` meaning two nested loops.

Based on advice I dug into the higher level modules as part of my original function in the Python source code:

```
 def sorted(lst):
        l = list(lst)
        l.sort()
        return l

def sort(self):
        sortable_files = sorted(map(os.path.split, self.files))

def set(self):
        if not self._value:
            self._value = True

            for fut in self._waiters:
                if not fut.done():
                    fut.set_result(True)
```

Now I'm really confused :)

Comment: The function `sorted` will presumably sort the items it is passed. There are a number of possible implementations of `sort`, each with different performance characteristics. Your example does not tell us anything about the particular implementation of `sorted` that is being used.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd `sorted` is a python built-in function. So the question boils down to: what is the python default doing ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upper bound of complexity of sorting algorithm is generally O(n*log(n)), as can be seen on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).
Then it depends how long it takes to cast the array to the set. From example you posted, we can see list is iterated over and in each step, value is checked whether it already is in the set or not.
According to [this](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt) the checking of existence of element in set has constant complexity, O(1), so whole constructing of set has complexity O(n) because of iterating over all elements.
But assuming that it is implemented by adding each element one by one, we must iterate over list to transform it to the set, which is O(n), and then we sort it, which is O(n*log(n)), and that results to total complexity O(n*log(n) + n) = O(n*log(n)).

Update:

Mapping also has linear complexity, because it iterates over whole set and maps each element, but since linear function grows slower than n*log(n), any linear operation here does not affect the O(n*log(n)), so the asymptotic complexity remains the same even with the mapping.

Comment: Composition is additive, not multiplicative. You create the set in O(n) time, then you sort the resulting set in O(n lg n) time. Ignoring the abuse of notation, O(n) + O(n lg n) = O(n + n lg n) = O(n lg n).

Comment: Yes, I corrected that immediately after I wrote it, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

(N logN) is the lower bound for some sorting algorithms​ like quick sort, heap sort, merge sort. They are generic comparison based algorithms. In worst case it can be O(N*N).

If the elements are going to be numeric, there are O(N) upper bound algorithms available like radix sort, counting sort and bucket sort.

If we are takiing about python library 'sorted' implementation, which TimSort implementation. TimSort is an optimised mergesort algorithm. It is stable and faster than the regular mergesort algorithm. It runs on O(N log N) in worst case and O(N) in best case (when list is already sorted).

Answer (score 0):

Beyond that "generic sorting" performance answers; as you are mentioning `sorted()` I assume you are asking about the big O values behind that built-in method in python.

Well, python is using [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort); and quoting from wikipedia:

> Timsort is a hybrid stable sorting algorithm, derived from merge sort and insertion sort, designed to perform well on many kinds of real-world data.
>
> In the worst case, Timsort takes O(n log n) comparisons to sort an array of n elements. In the best case, which occurs when the input is already sorted, it runs in linear time, meaning that it is an adaptive sorting algorithm.